# why result of regular expression match in not as expected?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, matching, openai-api

Here is a javascript code

```
const text = 'Hello, my name is John Doe.';
const matchesIterator = text.matchAll(/(\w+) (\w+)/g);
for (const match of matchesIterator) {
  console.log(match);
}
```

Here is its output:

```
[
  'my name',
  'my',
  'name',
  index: 7,
  input: 'Hello, my name is John Doe.',
  groups: undefined
]
[
  'is John',
  'is',
  'John',
  index: 15,
  input: 'Hello, my name is John Doe.',
  groups: undefined
]
```

I am wondering why John Doe is not in output.

I am trying to learn javascript regular expression.i given same code to chatGPT but it is not giving me proper output.

Comment: `name is` is also not in output. You probably need `/(\w+) (?=(\w+))/g`

Comment: what are you trying to match in the string?

Comment: You're matching sequences of two words separated by a space. After `my name` and `is John`, there are no more such sequences.

Comment: Because your regex does not match overlapping matches. Use `text.matchAll(/(?=\b(\w+)\s+(\w+))/g)` to get all of them.